# Possible to use extensions methods on a generic Enum Type? (not enum value)

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods, c#-7.3

There are some recent updates to C# that mean you can use `Enum` as a generic type constraint, and I'm trying to leverage this new feature to make some extension methods that will work on all enums.

Something like this:

```
public static class EnumToSequenceExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToSequence<T>(this T e)
        where T : Enum
    {
        foreach (T value in Enum.GetValues(e.GetType()))
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

What follows is how I'd like to use this method, which doesn't compile as it stands right now, it's an attempt to describe in pseudo-code what I'm trying to achieve;

```
IEnumerable<TestEnum> sequence = TestEnum.ToSequence();
```

Where `TestEnum` is an enum type I have, e.g.

```
public enum TestEnum { Hello, World }
```

I'm looking for some simple working code that is something very simple to use with a "fluent" feel to it, by which I mean it "reads well".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178965/discussion-between-cwharris-and-dan-rayson).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, not as long as `TestEnum` is an enum type, as you cannot extend these with members.

Since `TestEnum` is not an instance, and you can only create extension methods for instances, not for types, you cannot get `TestEnum.ToSequence()` to compile.

So the best you can get is to call the method manually, and not as an extension method.

Now, as [@Bagdan Gilevich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7594662/bagdan-gilevich) mentions in his comment, this should compile:

```
TestEnum.SomeEnumItem.ToSequence()
```

I'll leave opinions aside, you will have to make up your own mind if this is acceptable.

There is also a language feature suggestion for C# 8 (or later), called [Extension Everything](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11159). This *may* give you what you want but we'll have to see what happens with it.

Comment: Care to point out *what* is wrong with it? Note that the question is not if you can use enum as constraints, the question is if you can do `EnumType.ToSequence()`, to which the answer is still no.

Comment: It looks like static extension methods is one of the simplest parts of "Extension Everything" feature; are there some reasons why are you not sure about it?

Comment: Only that they always say that they reserve the right to postpone the release, or change it.

Answer (score 3):

[Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52066609/696056) is correct. Another alternative is simply using a static class with a static method and passing a generic parameter. C# 7.3+

```
public static class EnumHelpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> Sequence<TEnum>() where TEnum: struct, Enum
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
EnumHelpers.Sequence<SomeEnum>();
```

Comment: But you were saying his answer was wrong, now you are saying it's correct. lol, and posting the same thing he suggested as answer doesn't contribute to anything.

Comment: You're question is confusing. The title does not match the actual question. The answer to the title is "Yes, you can do that." And the answer to the containing question is "No, you can't do that." So technically it's ambiguous, BUT when I'm wrong I'm wrong. I don't build my house on sand, even if I've already bought the land.

Comment: This is an option I'd already tried, and I think it probably the best we'll have for now.  Personally I think prettier than having the first element included in your code in order to access an extension method.  I appreciate your answer(s)!